# ViewState in GridView ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I have a gridview that is connected to a datasource in the aspx code. The selected gridview row is hidden on clcik on button. I want to hide the row permenantly, even if user logs off and logs in the hidden row should not be shown. I have tried using ViewState but it doesnt work. Anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this.

My gridview:

```
edit Select Approve data 1 data 2 data 3
```

when the user clicks select and the approve button the row is hidden. I want all rows to be called except the one that is clicked, the clicked row should not be displayed at all. I did some research and found out the ViewState is the best but do not know how to accomplish it.

My Behind Code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=User-PC\\User;Initial Catalog=Subject Registration System;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = Session["username"].ToString();

        }

        con.Open();


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FullName FROM [Programme Leader] WHERE Username= '" + Label1.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();
        Label1.Text = reader["FullName"].ToString();
        reader.Close();

        con.Close();



        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string gd;
            gd = (string)ViewState["Gridview"];
        }



        Panel2.Visible=true;
        Panel3.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Panel2.Visible = true;

    }



    protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        Panel2.Visible = true;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView2_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

        Panel2.Visible = true;
        GridView2.DataBind();

    }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          GridView1.SelectedRow.Visible = false;

        ViewState["gridview"]=GridView1;



    }


    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Response.Redirect("~/Programme Leader Front Page.aspx");
    }



 }



}
```

Thank you

Comment: You will have to store that user's hidden row(s) somewhere permanent, like in your database.

Answer (score 0):

If the row that is hidden is tied to particular user, you could persist that to the database. So the new table would contain the primary key of the row from the gridview, and the user id. When performing the select for the gridview just exclude the rows for the user stored in the new table.

View state is the method that the ASP.NET page framework uses to preserve page and control values between round trips. View state won't work in your case because you want to the information persisted if the user logs out.